# Can't replace \t (TAB) from a string

Tags: javascript, php, json, regex, preg-replace

I have this JSON string that has returned from the database

```
[{"id":"1723","name":"Picanha bovina Maturatta  15,00   250 ","slug":"picanha-bovina-maturatta-15-00-250"}]
```

Actually, there are other stuff, but I removed it from the example.

This data is saved to the database when a user uploads a file in CSV format (so they can just export the data from Excel or Google Drive and don't need to add item by item in the CMS).

Now, when I get this data and send it to Javascript and parse it with JSON, it gives an "Unexpected token [tab]" error.

I tried several things to get it replaces

```
$json = json_encode($input);
$json = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n", "\t", "   "), "", $json);
$json = implode(' ',explode("\t", $json));
$json = preg_replace(array('/\s{2,}/', '/[\t\n]/'), ' ', $json);
$json = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $json));
$json = preg_replace('!\s+!m', ' ', $json);
```

None of these work. Why not?

Note 1: if I use /g in the REGEX string goes blank
Note 2: I'm sure there is a \tab character because if I CTRL+F on Chrome or copy/paste it to Gedit or http://json.parser.online.fr/ I can see it.
Note 3: I changed the input directly on code, something like "test\t\t\t\ttest" and it still doenst work
Note 4: Javascript can replace it: `JSON.parse(PRODUCTS.split("\t").join(" "))` and it works

Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace('/\t+/', '', $string)
```